# Cisco ASA Nat 8.4

Tags: cisco, nat, cisco-asa

I'm trying to get port forwarding on my ASA working.

I'm using:

```
object network server1
 nat (inside,outside) static interface service tcp 25 25
```

and an access list, and it works fine, however, I can't add more than one nat statement to it.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need separate object statements for each port or you need a dedicated IP address for your server (which would be preferred). Here's what each one looks like

If you would like to do PAT:

> object network server1_smtp
>   host 192.168.1.100
>   nat (inside,outside) static interface service tcp 25 25
>   !
>   object network server1_https
>   host 192.168.1.100
>   nat (inside,outside) static interface servcie tcp 443 443
>   !
>   access-list outside_access_in extended permit tcp any host 192.168.1.100 eq 25
>   access-list outside_access_in extended permit tcp any host 192.168.1.100 eq 443

If you would like to give it its own IP address:

> object network server1
>   host 192.168.1.100
>   nat (inside,outside) static 1.1.1.1
>   !
>   access-list outside_access_in extended permit tcp any host 192.168.1.100 eq 25
>   access-list outside_access_in extended permit tcp any host 192.168.1.100 eq 443